# Xamarin Forms Switch Toggled event doesn't bind with viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a Forms XAML Page and in there I have a listview, and each element has a Switch (xamarin default). I can bind the data from the items to the listview, but I cannot subscrive the Switch event "Toggled", as it causes the item not to show. I also tried with ICommand and Command, as it is instructed to do with buttons, but the result is the same, nothing shown. How can I handle the switch toggle from the my viewmodel?

### View

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TouristicWallet.Views.WalletManagementPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TouristicWallet.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TouristicWallet.Converters"
             >

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:WalletManagementViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:CurrencyIdToCodeConverter x:Key="idToCodeConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="MyCurrencies" ItemsSource="{Binding Currencies, Mode=OneWay}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="{Binding Currency.Initials, Mode=OneWay}" />
              <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Toggled="{Binding Toggled}"
                      />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### ViewModel

```
public class WalletManagementViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private readonly List<OwnedCurrencyWrapper> _currencies = new List<OwnedCurrencyWrapper>();
    public List<OwnedCurrencyWrapper> Currencies { get { return _currencies; } }

    public WalletManagementViewModel()
    {
        CurrencyDataAccess cda = new CurrencyDataAccess();
        foreach (var item in cda.GetCurrencies())
        {
            Currencies.Add(new OwnedCurrencyWrapper(item));
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Currencies));
    }

    public class OwnedCurrencyWrapper
    {
        public Currency Currency { get; private set; }
        public Boolean IsOwned { get; set; }
        public ICommand Toggled { get; set; }


        public OwnedCurrencyWrapper(Currency currency)
        {
            Currency = currency;
            WalletDataAccess wda = WalletDataAccess.Instance;
            IsOwned = wda.IsOwned(Currency.Id);

            Toggled = new Command(() => Update());
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            WalletDataAccess wda = WalletDataAccess.Instance;
            if (IsOwned) wda.RemoveOwnedCurrency(Currency.Id);
            else wda.OwnCurrency(Currency.Id);

        }

        public void Toggled_handler(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            Update();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not using any mvvm framework

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First off a Switch can not bind to a `Command`. See:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/#Commanding_with_ViewModels

From the above, the Forms controls that can bind to an `ICommand` are:

- Button
- MenuItem
- ToolbarItem
- SearchBar
- TextCell (and hence also
  ImageCell )
- ListView
- TapGestureRecognizer

you can just do the following to run code in the View's code behind file, do this in the XAML:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Toggled="Handle_Toggled" />
```

And then in the Code behind file:

```
void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Alternately, since you are binding, you could run code in the actual `OwnedCurrencyWrapper` class (which is what you seem to want) just by adding code to the setter for `IsOwned`. IN this case, don't assign anything to the Toggled property of your switch::

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And then in your `OwnedCurrencyWrapper` class:

```
bool _isOwned;
public bool IsOwned { 
    get 
    {
        return _isOwned;
    } 
    set
    {
        _isOwned = value;
        // Do any other stuff you want here
    }
}
```

That said, your binding is not complete since your view model is not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so changes made directly to the view model will not be reflected in the UI. For more info on binding with Forms MVVM, see: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

UPDATE: I was not aware of Behaviors in Xamarin Forms. See:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior

> In the context of commanding, behaviors are a useful approach for connecting a control to a command. In addition, they can also be used to associate commands with controls that were not designed to interact with commands. This sample demonstrates using a behavior to invoke a command when an event fires.

So this should allow you to bind the Toggled event to a Command.

Comment: I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, it's in my custom ViewModelBase class which all my ViewModels are extending. Your answer (both, and I am keeping the second way in my code for now) actually is the way I worked the issue around, but this is not very "MVVM" like.

Comment: Here is another option, Behaviors:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior
"behaviors are a useful approach for connecting a control to a command. In addition, they can also be used to associate commands with controls that were not designed to interact with commands. This sample demonstrates using a behavior to invoke a command when an event fires." I was not aware of Behaviors before, sorry.

Comment: Just bind IsToggled to a property in the model and implement your logic in the Getter/Setter.

Answer (score 9):

If you adhere to Prism framework you may easily wire an event to a command. Your xaml will look like in the following example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                 xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                 x:Class="TouristicWallet.Views.WalletManagementPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20">
            <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned}"  x:Name="IsOwnedSwitch">
                <Switch.Behaviors>
                    <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Toggled"  Command="{Binding ToggleIsOwnedCommand}"/>
                </Switch.Behaviors>
            </Switch>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 7):

As others have mentioned, you should bind the Toggled event to an eventHandler behavior which will forward a command.  The code below can be used.

```html
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding SwitchEnabled}"  x:Name="MySwitch">
    <Switch.Behaviors>
    <!-- behaviors namespace comes from "Xamarin.Forms Behaviors" nuget  -->
        <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="Toggled">
            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ToggleSwitchCommand}" />
        </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
    </Switch.Behaviors>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Does this work for you. Becuase I've managed to get the Event to command behaviour working for other controls but can't get it to work with this

Comment: Yes, it works for me.  Its probably something small you're missing. I can give you another set of eyes if you want.  I'm on the Xamarin forums with the same username, just no space between first and lastname.  Send me a message and I'll take a look if you want.

Comment: That be great thanks, ill be back in the office tomorrow

Comment: I can't add behaivors I get this error:  Error: 'behaviors' is an undeclared

Comment: @NoeMirandaFranco Download the Xamarin.Forms Behaviors nuget and reference it as a namespace at the top of the page.  I updated my answer to include a comment to the namespace.

Comment: @lyndonhughey Thanks I have downloaded https://github.com/nuitsjp/Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack and it works well.

Comment: And of course this wouldn't be an option for SwitchCell, I mean that would make too much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Solution : After doing some R&D i found the root cause of this issue,

Error Code in very first post:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Toggled="{Binding Toggled}"
                      />
```

**Just do Two steps.**

1. Declare event listener function **OnToggled** in **ContentPage** class and **not into your ViewModel class** that you need to bind

In your **ContentPage** class

```
void OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e){

}
```

2. change **Toggled="{Binding Toggled}"** == to ==> **Toggled="OnToggled"**

it will fix the issue, **Don't know why it don't work for event listener function declared in ViweModel class**.

--I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it in a very easy way.

=> Goal: Get items with a switch control in a listview to respond to a command.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TouristicWallet.Views.WalletManagementPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TouristicWallet.ViewModels"
             x:Name="pageName"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TouristicWallet.Converters"
             >

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:WalletManagementViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:CurrencyIdToCodeConverter x:Key="idToCodeConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="MyCurrencies" ItemsSource="{Binding Currencies, Mode=OneWay}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="{Binding Currency.Initials, Mode=OneWay}" />
  

 <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Selected}"   HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                  <Switch.Behaviors>
                                            <b:EventToCommandBehavior 
                                              EventName="Toggled"  Command=" 
                                                    {Binding                                                 
                                                      Path=BindingContext.SendCommand, 
                                                    Source={x:Reference 
                                                   Name=pageName}}" />
                                            </Switch.Behaviors>
                                        </Switch>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In ViewModel
Define your Command /ICommand

```
public ICommand SendCommand { get; set; }

SendCommand = new Command(() => //do something.....);
```

Please Take special note of the areas in bold.