# How can I stop a Toggled Event on a switch from being fired as a page is loaded?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application has a switch set up in XAML and backend C# code that responds to the toggle event

```
<ViewCell x:Name="ss">
   <Switch x:Name="ssSwitch" Toggled="SsSwitch"   />
</ViewCell>

void SsSwitch(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) {
    // Code to update database here
}
```

When the page first loads I notice that the SwSwitch Toggled event is called.

Is there some way that I can stop this happening as there is no reason to do an update of the database on start up.

Comment: If you had a loading flag you could make sure the view has actually finished loading before responding to the toggle action...

Comment: If you are using MVVM pattern - you can use `PropertyChanged` event or property setter to detect value update (instead of Toggled event). An example can be found in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071201/7292772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option-1: Use property setter in ViewModel

If you are using MVVM - the simplest option to resolve this would be to **use  property setter** to detect value update (as mentioned on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071201/7292772)). But this option doesn't work if you want to call awaitable methods here. Also, as a best practice it is recommended that properties shouldn't implement [any time consuming operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182181.aspx#Anchor_1).

```
bool _isToggled;
public bool IsToggled 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return _isToggled;
    } 
    set
    {
        _isToggled = value;
        // Add your update code here
    }
}
```

### Option-2: Use `PropertyChanged` event in ViewModel

The next option would be to **subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event** in your viewmodel and appropriately handle it. This allows you to define async handlers which in turn can await asynchronous methods.

```
// Subscribe to event while constructing/assigning viewmodel
// viewCellVM.PropertyChanged += CategoryVM_PropertyChanged;

async void ViewCellVM_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewCellVM.IsToggled))
    {
        //call update code here
        //await DB.Update();
    }
}
```

### Option-3: Override `OnAppearing()` in ViewCell

Another option is to make sure that the `Toggled` event handler is assigned after the `BindingContext` is updated on the `ViewCell`. So, I did a quick experiment to track the order `Handle_Toggled`, `OnBindingContextChanged`, `OnAppearing` methods are called while loading the view. The order turned out to be:

```
Handle_Toggled
OnBindingContextChanged
OnAppearing
```

Hence, **assigning the handler in `OnAppearing`** method (in ViewCell's code-behind) should also work for this case:

```
//XAML:<Switch x:Name="switchBtn" IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled}" />
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    switchBtn.Toggled += Handle_Toggled;
    Debug.WriteLine("OnAppearing");
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    switchBtn.Toggled -= Handle_Toggled;
    Debug.WriteLine("OnDisappearing");
}
```

This way `Handle_Toggled` will only be called when the user toggles the switch.

Answer (score 4):

With your code above the `Switch` shouldn't trigger the event on first start. It triggers only if you have bound your `IsToggled` property with your ViewModel! The reason for that is, that the Page is initialized first, the ViewModel toggles the Switch and then the event is getting fired.

First solution would be to handle the `IsToggled` property and the `Toggled` event both from the code-behind (not recommended if you are mvvm-ing your code). Better solution would be to handle both from the ViewModel.

The problem is, that the `Switch` Control doesn't have a `Command` property. You have to use a Behaviour to bind to a `Command.` Sharada Gururaj already posted a Link above with a good explanation.

Here is the short Solution form Sharada Gururajs stackoverflow link: [Xamarin Forms Switch Toggled event doesn't bind with viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070613/xamarin-forms-switch-toggled-event-doesnt-bind-with-viewmodel)

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled}">
<Switch.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="Toggled">
    <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ToggleSwitchCommand}" />
    </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
</Switch.Behaviors>
```

Further Informations:

- https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64374/switch-with-istoggled-binding-is-throwing-toggled-event-on-init-when-bound-value-is-true