# Xamarin Switch ToggleEvent causes loop

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I got a problem similiar to this

[How can I stop a Toggled Event on a switch from being fired as a page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821453/how-can-i-stop-a-toggled-event-on-a-switch-from-being-fired-as-a-page-is-loaded)

Except my error is that when I toggle my switch it causes a infinity loop at the InitGroupMethod. It's because I'm changing the toggled event programmatically during this. Which triggers the toggleEvent again. What I want to happen is that when the category is disabled, all bottom categories will no longer be added and the page will be refreshed.

Currently the load correctly when opening the page, and if you save the list and then revisit it. But can't get the view to update when the switch is toggled withoutinfinity loop.

Image here https://gyazo.com/eedd4ab2ab3cd892ef57cd2d245d7dd1?token=d39388a4b5b726f6c5e2f44219dd4b6f

How do I get the view to update? I've tried to cause a custom switchcell and desubb from the toggleevent before changing this, but couldn't access the x:name due to it being a list. I've tried turning it into a switchcell too.xa

The list of brandsviewmodel

```
     public class BrandViewModel : ObservableCollection<SubBrandViewModel>, INotifyPropertyChanged
                {
                    private bool isEnabledBrand;

                    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                    public string HouseCode { get; set; }

                    public List<SubBrandViewModel> SubBrands { get; set; }

                    public bool IsEnabledBrand
                    {
                        get => isEnabledBrand;
                        set
                        {
                            isEnabledBrand = value;
                            NotifyPropertyChanged();
                        }
                    }
            }
```

The PageViewModel

```
              public ObservableCollection<Grouping<BrandViewModel, SubBrandViewModel>> GroupedItems { get; set; }

                public List<BrandViewModel> Categories { get; set; }

                public List<string> AllowedBrands { get; set; }

                public List<string> AllowedSubBrands { get; set; }


        public void ComputeUiBrandStatus()
                {
                    Dictionary<string, bool> tableWithStrings = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

                    foreach (string code in AllowedBrands)
                    {
                        if (!tableWithStrings.ContainsKey(code))
                        {
                            tableWithStrings.Add(code, true);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (BrandViewModel category in Categories)
                    {
                        if (tableWithStrings.ContainsKey(category.HouseCode))
                        {
                            category.IsEnabledBrand = true;
                        }

                        if (category.SubBrands != null)
                        {
                            foreach (SubBrandViewModel subCategory in category.SubBrands)
                            {
                                if (tableWithStrings.ContainsKey(subCategory.Code))
                                {
                                    subCategory.IsEnabledSubBrand = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

         private void InitGrouppedData()
                {

                    GroupedItems.Clear();
                    var items = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<BrandViewModel, SubBrandViewModel>>();
                    foreach (BrandViewModel category in Categories)
                    {
                        List<SubBrandViewModel> subCategory = new List<SubBrandViewModel>();
                        if (category.SubBrands != null && category.IsEnabledBrand)
                        {
                            subCategory.AddRange(category.SubBrands);
                        }

                        Grouping<BrandViewModel, SubBrandViewModel> group = new Grouping<BrandViewModel, SubBrandViewModel>(category, subCategory);

                        items.Add(group);
                    }

                    GroupedItems = items;
                }


           private void OnToggleSwitch(object obj)
                {
                   RemoveOrAddSubBrands();
                }
```

The Page

```
 <ListView
          ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedItems}"
          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key.HouseCode}"
          GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key.HouseCode}"
          HasUnevenRows="False"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">

                            <FlexLayout.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="FlexLayout" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference SwitchParent}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBkColor}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </FlexLayout.Triggers>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Key.HouseCode}" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" >
                                <Label.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference SwitchParent},Path=IsToggled}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Label.Triggers>
                            </Label>

                            <Switch x:Name="SwitchParent" IsToggled="{Binding Key.IsEnabledBrand}" >
                                <Switch.Behaviors>
                                    <controls:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Toggled" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference BrandPage}, Path=ViewModel.SwitchToggledCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Switch.Behaviors>
                            </Switch>
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ViewCell>


                   </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell >
                                <FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" Margin="30,0,0,0">

                                    <FlexLayout.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="FlexLayout" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switch}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBkColor}" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                    </FlexLayout.Triggers>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Code}" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" >
                                        <Label.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switch},Path=IsToggled}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Label.Triggers>
                                    </Label>

                                    <Switch x:Name="Switch" IsToggled="{Binding IsEnabledSubBrand}" />

                                </FlexLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: the simplest thing to do would be to create a bool Updating that you set whenever the event fires - and if it is true then ignore any new events that are fired until the initial event is done and you reset Updating

Comment: So what method would I set it in?

Comment: Whichever handler is causing the loop, I guess

Comment: Did not really solve it, I tried it everywhere.

Comment: Without knowing more about what's happening I can't really recommend anything else.  Try revising your question to clearly explain the chain of events  a -> b -> c that leads to the loop/recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a setter for a property which invokes PropertyChanged, guard the actual update and signaling of the event:

```
                public bool IsEnabledBrand
                {
                    get => isEnabledBrand;
                    set
                    {
                        if (isEnabledBrand != value)
                        {
                            isEnabledBrand = value;
                            NotifyPropertyChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The whole point is that you don't want to raise the OnPropertyChanged event unless the property did change.  There isn't quite enough of your code here to know if this is the problem, but it is worth keeping this design point in mind, as it can avoid problems.

Comment: Did not solve it sadly. The code still works when I use it to trigger it with a button, but it doesn't work when I use the switch event. As for some reason the switch toggle event is triggering itself whenever its group is assigned in the initgroupmethod.

Comment: The next step would be to run it under the debugger and grab a call stack when it's a few layers down the infinite recursion. That will help give a clearer idea of what step to take next.

Comment: I figured it out excatly what is triggering it. Apparently when my GroupedItems is called it triggers the Events inside it. Why does my collection call it's event when being getted?

Comment: Managed to fix it! The problem had something to do with me binding with my IsToggled property and that binding caused a firing of the event whenever the property was touched programatically. However this was fixed by not using the binding, passing the object with {Binding .} and then casting the object back to my class, foreaching my original collection (the one not in use by my viewmodel and just the getonly) and then regrouping and setting them from there. Probably not the best way, but at least it works. Been stuck on this for months

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my solution for my particular looping switch problem in case it could be helpful for anyone else with a similar scenario:

I simply had to make sure my toggle event handler was using the `ToggledEventArgs` value and not the `IsToggled` binding variable value.

Given Switch in XAML:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding UserIsFollowingOwner}" Toggled="ToggleFollow"/>
```

Changed `Toggled` Event Handler From:

```
async void ToggleFollow(object sender, ToggledEventArgs args) {
    if (viewModel.UserIsFollowingOwner) { 
        await viewModel.UnFollowOwner();
    } else {
        await viewModel.FollowOwner();
    }
}
```

To:

```
async void ToggleFollow(object sender, ToggledEventArgs args) {
    if (args.Value) { 
        await viewModel.FollowOwner();
    } else {
        await viewModel.UnFollowOwner();
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: If you use async void it will cause exceptions to not happens.
I.e it's like having a try catch without the catch.

Comment: Error happens if event handler is not `async void`: 
"XamlC error XFC0002: EventHandler ... with correct signature not found"

...My understanding is that `async void` for Xamarin event handlers is expected/ok.

Comment: Partially true

https://johnthiriet.com/removing-async-void/

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the info!  Might have to create a refactor story ;-)