# How do I prevent the OnToggled Handler from firing in a view cell?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, event-handling, toggle

I am creating a filter menu that is dynamically populated with options. The menu is a grouped ListView. Each option is a class with a `OptionName` and `IsFiltered` property and the corresponding Switch is bound to the `IsFiltered` property. I have three buttons on this filter menu: one to clear all filters, one to apply the selected filters, and one to cancel, which is intended to discard any toggles that occur since last opening the filter menu. It is important to note that the filter menu 'remembers' which filters are toggled after you Apply.

The Clear and Apply buttons work great, but I am having trouble implementing the Cancel button. Essentially what it does now is keep track of all toggles that have occurred since opening the menu by adding that filter option to an internal Collection when a Toggle even is triggered. If the user selects Cancel, it iterates through all of those toggle values and reverts them. The logic works great when I step through. The problem I'm having is that if there are filters that have been applied previously, the Toggle Handler event is fired for each of those "already selected" filters when the Filter Menu page appears. This causes those "already selected" filters to be added to the "newly selected" list. I'd like to find a way to suppress the firing of the Toggle handler in this case.

I've found several solutions, but haven't been able to get any to work. The most promising so far was [option 3 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821453/how-can-i-stop-a-toggled-event-on-a-switch-from-being-fired-as-a-page-is-loaded?rq=1), which sets the Switch's handler event *after* appearing, but as the Switch lives in a DataTemplate, I can't access it by name, as there could be an infinite number of Switches.

There are other solutions given online which seem to have been successful for others but don't have enough context for me to figure out how to implement it in my scenario. For reference, I've included the containing ListView's xaml code, the code behind for the xaml page with any relevant code, as well as the ViewModel with any relevant code.

The relevant code is below:

**ListView XAML**

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FilterOptionList}"
                          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                          HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell Height="25">
                                <StackLayout Padding="3, 20, 3, 2">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           FontSize="Small"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid Margin="15, 0, 40, 0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding OptionName}"
                                           FontSize="Micro"
                                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <Switch x:Name="filterSwitch"
                                            IsToggled="{Binding IsFiltered, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            Toggled="Switch_OnToggled"
                                            Grid.Column="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

**Code Behind**

```cs
namespace MyProject.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FilterMenu : ContentPage
    {
        public FilterMenu(ObservableRangeCollection<MyObject> myObjects, ObservableCollection<FilterOptionGroup> filterOptionList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new FilterMenuViewModel(Navigation, myObjects, filterOptionList);
        }

        private void CloseButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (BindingContext as FilterMenuViewModel)?.Cancel();
        }

        private void ClearButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (BindingContext as FilterMenuViewModel)?.ClearFilter();
        }

        private void ApplyFilterButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (BindingContext as FilterMenuViewModel)?.ApplyFilter();
        }

        private void Switch_OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            FilterOption filterOption = (sender as Switch).Parent.BindingContext as FilterOption;
            (BindingContext as FilterMenuViewModel)?.ToggleFilter(sender, e, filterOption);
        }
    }
}
```

**Filter Menu View Model**

```cs
public class FilterMenuViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; private set; }
        private readonly INavigation _navigation;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        List<FilterOption> newlyCheckedFilters = new List<FilterOption>();
        public ObservableCollection<FilterOptionGroup> FilterOptionList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FilterOptionGroup>() ;

        public FilterMenuViewModel(INavigation navigation, ObservableCollection<MyObject> myObjects, ObservableCollection<FilterOptionGroup> filterOptionList )
        {
            _navigation = navigation;
            this.MyObjects = myObjects;
            FilterOptionList = filterOptionList;


            PopulateCategories();
        }

        private void PopulateFilter(string name, List<string> newOptions)
        {
            // Code to create the Filter Options list...
        }

        private void PopulateCategories()
        {
            // Code to create the Filter Options list...
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }

        public async void Cancel()
        {
            foreach (var filterOption in newlyCheckedFilters)
            {
                filterOption.IsFiltered = !filterOption.IsFiltered;
            }

            await _navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        public void ClearFilter()
        {
            foreach (var group in FilterOptionList)
            {
                foreach (var option in group)
                {
                    option.IsFiltered = false;
                }
            }

        }

        public async void ApplyFilter()
        {
            await _navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        public void ToggleFilter(object sender, ToggledEventArgs toggledEventArgs, FilterOption filterOption)
        {
            newlyCheckedFilters.Add(filterOption);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share us a basic demo to reproduce this issue as I'm not totally understand the issue through your description? Also, I agree that make a copy of the filter list and then you can reset it by this list.

Answer (score 0):

use a `bool` to control the toggled handler.  Set it to `true` after you've completed any initialization (in `OnAppearing`, for example)

```
    bool init = false;

    private void Switch_OnToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!bool) return;

        FilterOption filterOption = (sender as Switch).Parent.BindingContext as FilterOption;
        (BindingContext as FilterMenuViewModel)?.ToggleFilter(sender, e, filterOption);
    }
```

Comment: I added ```private bool init;``` to the code behind, set it to true at the beginning of the constructor and back to false after setting the binding context. I then added ```if(init) {return;}``` to the handler. This didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: That sounds like you're just inverting the logic I suggested, which is fine.  Where are you setting BindingContext?

Comment: Binding Context is set in the constructor for the code behind:                          
`public FilterMenu(ObservableRangeCollection<MyObject> myObjects, ObservableCollection<FilterOptionGroup> filterOptionList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new FilterMenuViewModel(Navigation, myObjects, filterOptionList);
        }`

Comment: It should probably be noted that in my research I've seen that the Handler event is set before any other initialization processes. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: try setting `init = true` in OnAppearing

Comment: I mean set it to false, so that the event handler only executes after OnAppearing has fired

Comment: The bool is false by default. Should I set it to true in OnAppearing() and change the condition to ```if(!init) {return;}```?

Comment: That's what I would do.  But however you set it up, the key is that you do NOT want the event handler to execute until after OnAppearing

Comment: without actually debugging your code I can't say what's wrong - but the other approach would be to make a complete copy of the filter list in the constructor, and use that as a refernece when you need to reset

Comment: Yeah that was another option I was thinking about. I'm going to play around with this a bit more and then I'll try that if I don't make any progress.