# Switch/Label inside ListView's ViewCell not accessible by name

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used Switch to toggle data, if I add an event it work's fine. I'm trying to remove handler on data binding so that the event handler stay put. But I'm not getting the element by it's name.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" x:Name="DynamicListView" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" ItemSelected="DynamicListViewItemSelected" IsVisible="false" WidthRequest="380" RowHeight="75">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
               <StackLayout Orientation ="Horizontal" >
                   <Label x:Name="configLabel" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource BigBlackLabelLeft}"  />
                   <Switch x:Name="configSwitch" HorizontalOptions="End" OnColor="LightSeaGreen" IsToggled="{Binding IsVisible}" Toggled="HandleSwitchToggledByUser" />
               </StackLayout>
           </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So on the code behind I'm trying to access Label/Switch by `configLabel`/`configSwitch` but i'm getting error saying `The name configSwitch 
 does not exist on the current context`. I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: you can't access items in templates from the code behind by name because there may be 0 or 1000 copies of that template created at run time.  If you would explain exactly what you're trying to do we could suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I'm trying to use switch as user settings, for example turn on/off wifi. Here I'm using `Label` as placeholder for text and `Switch` to toggle. My idea was to capture the binding object on the event to get what exact value user wants to modify.

Comment: try `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`, then you can get that value from the `sender` in your event handler

Comment: I don't think command is available in Switch, I'm looking this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070613/xamarin-forms-switch-toggled-event-doesnt-bind-with-viewmodel` post

Comment: use can just use the BindingContext of sender instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two subviews in the `ViewCell`, I would access the control in this way:

First, I created a custom mySwitch and add a bindable property `name` to it, you can use this name later to figure out which `switch` you are toggling:

```
    public class mySwitch : Switch
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty nameProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create("name", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), null);

        public string name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(nameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(nameProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

In xaml, here I write a listView as an example and I set binding to the name of switch as the same as text of label:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>wifi</x:String>
                <x:String>sound</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
                            <local:mySwitch name="{Binding .}"  HorizontalOptions="End" OnColor="LightSeaGreen" IsToggled="{Binding IsVisible}" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

in code behind, you can access the switch by `sender`, access the ParentStackLayout by `sender.parent`, and access the label by `(Label)ParentStackLayout.Children[0]`, then use the name of switch to distinguish switch and change the text of corresponding 
 configLabel:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        // access switch
        var Switch_ToggledHandler = (mySwitch)sender;

        // access Parent Layout for Sender  
        StackLayout ParentStackLayout = (StackLayout)Switch_ToggledHandler.Parent;

        // access the Label "configLabel"  
        Label configLabel = (Label)ParentStackLayout.Children[0];


        if (Switch_ToggledHandler.IsToggled)
        {
            switch (Switch_ToggledHandler.name)
            {
                case "wifi":
                    configLabel.Text = "wifi open";
                    break;
                case "sound":
                    configLabel.Text = "sound is open";
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }

        }
        else {

            switch (Switch_ToggledHandler.name)
            {
                case "wifi":
                    configLabel.Text = "wifi off";
                    break;
                case "sound":
                    configLabel.Text = "sound is off";
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a gif:

[image: gif]

I also upload my demo [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Access-control-in-ViewCell-xamarin.forms) and you can check it. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the BindingContext of your ViewCell in the toggled event, that's very simple: simply cast the sender parameter to a View and its BindingContext to the class of the items shown in the list, then read from it the value that you need:

```cs
    private void HandleSwitchToggledByUser(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is View v && v.BindingContext is ItemClass item)
        {
            var switchName = item.Name;
        }
    }
```