# Binding switch Toggled property

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, cross-platform, maui

I would like to know if is possible to bind a Toggled property of switch control, and if so, then how?

```
<Switch
Grid.Column="1"
HorizontalOptions="End" 
VerticalOptions="Center"
Margin="20,0"
OnColor="#00CD00"
ThumbColor="White"
Toggled="Binding SomeFunction"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: With IsToggled="{Binding X}".

Comment: Sometimes just RDFM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/switch?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: You can bind "IsToggled", but you cannot bind "Toggled". Thats what I'm asking for.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer on this topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070613/xamarin-forms-switch-toggled-event-doesnt-bind-with-viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

You could use Maui CommunityToolkit [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior).

First, please install CommunityToolkit.Maui Nuget and initialize the package.

In MauiProgram.cs, add `UseMauiCommunityToolkit()` :

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
...
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
...
```

Then in xaml, we add the **EventToCommandBehavior** to Switch. It allows us to map Toggled event on Switch to a Command defined in viewModel (if use MVVM way).

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
...
     xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">


<Switch             
   HorizontalOptions="End" 
   VerticalOptions="Center"
   Margin="20,0"
   OnColor="#00CD00"
   ThumbColor="White"
   >
   <Switch.Behaviors>
       <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
           EventName="Toggled"
           Command="{Binding ToggledCommand}" />
   </Switch.Behaviors>
```

In cs file, set the BindingContext for MainPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
...
```

In viewModel file, define the ToggledCommand, such like this:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public Command ToggledCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                //you could add your function here                  
                Console.WriteLine("123");
            });
        }
    }
```

When you toggle the switch, the code in ToggledCommand in ViewModel will execute.

Hope it works.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesnt works. Any ideas why?

Comment: May I ask if ToggledCommand in viewmodel fired when switch toggled? Did you set the BindingContext of MainPage to ViewModel.

Comment: @siflJebatkundy I have updated my answer and tested on iOS and Android. When switch is toggled, the command in ViewModel will fire.

Comment: On the viewModel site RelayCommand can also be used to bind https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand